# Redirect in controller using RedirectToAction malfunction

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Normally google is my best friend but this problem I can't figure out or even understand.

I have an action in my controller that I use for selecting which follow up action in my controller to use, based on user input (see image)
[image: Select sction and press "SÖK" and enter code at ActionSelector]

This redirect work like a charm, it's when the action I'm redirected to is finished as the problem arises. In my action I fetch some much needed data for the web site. When tha data is fetched the action are supposed to redirect to a generic action, that in turn will present my view. The "middleware" action redirect correctly and it also send the parameters but the "recieving action" don't handle or recieve the parameters.

[image]

I'm totally clueless here, is it not possible to redirect to an action that in turn redirect to another action or what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route specification looks a bit odd.

I think it should be possibly:

```
[HttpGet("Customer/Device/{id}")]
public IActionResult Device(string id, bool like)
{
}
```

Now the URL it tried to redirect you to should work. Id from URL, and the `like` parameter from query.

If you want both in URL:

```
[HttpGet("Customer/Device/{id}/{like}")]
public IActionResult Device(string id, bool like)
{
}
```